# setting devise form input values to the right side of a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some edits to the devise registration pages on my rails application. Basically all I'm trying to do is have the labels on the left hand side of the div and the actual inputs on the left hand side of my div.  I've been using css floating attributes, and yes they move to the right....but they stack on the corners (instead of on top of each other see image.).  Would anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

html

```
 .control-group
  = f.input :email,
      input_html: { class: "testHere" }, 
      label: "Email", 
      required: true

  = f.input :password,       
    input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password", class: "testHere" },
    required: true,
    hint: (" #{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)

  = f.input :password_confirmation,
    input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password", class: "testHere" },
    required: true
```

css

```
.registrationContainer{
  max-width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  opacity: .9;
}

.control-group{
  padding: 10px;
}

.testHere{
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What html preprocessor is?

Comment: Please post a gist of the generated html.